# Xamarin.forms project in Mac terminal without Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono, devops

I'm trying to build a job for Xamarin.forms project in mac terminal without UI method. but, not sure which are the tools are mandatory to be installed. Could anyone help here ?

1. Installed : Dotnet Core 6 version of visual studio SDK
2. Build need to be fully in terminal(mac-command line)
3. Need to do without visual studio application

Answer (score 0):

Why not try build the app from the command line using MSBuild and see what errors it gives you. That way, you can find out what's missing and add things until it builds.

I'm using this command to build my apps from Windows (you may need to change a few things on Mac):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" C:\Projects\MyApp\src\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\MyApp.iOS.csproj /p:Platform=iPhone /p:BuildIpa=true /p:IpaPackageDir=C:\Projects\MyApp\artifacts\App_iOS /p:IpaPackageName=MyApp.ipa /p:ServerAddress=192.168.0.23 /p:ServerUser="Username" /p:ServerPassword=123456SafePassword /p:ContinueOnDisconnected=false /p:Configuration=Release /restore /target:Build /verbosity:Normal
```

Here's some useful info on [Continuous Integration with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ci/).

Comment: Thanks, @michal. for the reply. I have not installed Visual studio in my mac machine, instead i have installed Dotnet core 6 version as a command line tool activity. Do you have any idea, how it works in mac terminal? Note: 1. Build need to be fully in terminal(mac-command line) 2.Need to do without visual studio application

Comment: I'm not sure you even can build Xamarin.Forms apps using the dotnet CLI. That's why I opted to use MSBuild instead. However, you definitely can build .NET MAUI apps with the dotnet CLI, I'm using that at the moment. By the way, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022) mentions how to get MSBuild without Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 'dotnet msbuild' but getting errors
Firstly, I got error as ‘Xamarn.android.csharp.target ’. then, manually installed Xamarin.android. and the error went out.
Secondly, getting error as ‘error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks ’

Comment: @SakthivelP In general you cannot use `dotnet` or `dotnet msbuild` as that runs the .NET Core version of MSBuild which is not designed to execute Xamarin tasks. Your only option is to use Mono's MSBuild or just `msbuild` with VS for Mac installed. .NET Core MSBuild/CLI only supports MAUI apps (.NET 6/7), which your Xamarin apps must migrate to as early as possible.

Comment: Thanks Lex, for your notes. However, when i do the 'dotnet build', I'm getting error "MSB3644: The reference assemblies for MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application."

Comment: Thanks @Lex. I will be executing Mono's msbuild , do we have any forum/discussion/articles to  execute Mono's msbuild in Mac (terminal). Also , Do we need to install any pre-request tools ?

Comment: @SakthivelP if you have VS for Mac installed there, then `msbuild --version` can give you the answer at terminal.

Comment: hello @LexLi, I have installed Mono. Now, i have mono's msbuild.